# "Yum Install package-name" to different directory

Tags: linux, centos, yum

Is there anybody who knows that how to install package using yum on different directory but not in root(/) directory ?

Whenever I'm using "yum install package-name" command by default it is installing package in root(/) directory but i want to install package in different directory.

Even rpm -ivh -r /path/path package.rpm doesn't work for me. I'm getting error: open of docker-engine.rpm failed: No such file or directory

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Yum does not appear to support that capability.  See this Red Hat [solution](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/199433).

Yum has an `--installroot` option but that is intended for `chroot` installs and would basically create a whole new environment where dependencies must be resolved.

As for `rpm`, it has `--relocate OLDPATH=NEWPATH` and `--prefix NEWPATH` which will allow you to change the install path for rpms marked as *relocatable* which will not apply to all packages.  In general, it is not considered a good idea.

Alternatively, you could obtain the source code for the rpm and rebuild it yourself with the desired path.

I see a `docker` error from your post which may change everything I've just said.

Comment: Thanks. My root (/) directory is no more supporting package installation cause of not enough disk space in root directory. 

I'm getting error like At least 100MB more space needed on the / filesystem.

Comment: It sounds like you may be better off investigating space issues and freeing up your disk.

Comment: That said, I think the question is still valid for users who have other reasons for needing to install in non-root areas.  For example, I found this because I need to provide different users of the system with different versions of tools, and I can't yet shift all of them over to using containers (though that is my plan).

Answer (score 2):

In theory it might be possible to use the `--installroot` option to install the package in a different place. I don't think it is a good idea. The package installs files in various locations in the filesystem. So even if it is technically possible it would be a nightmare to make it work properly.

On top of that I think your issue is a different one, as already proposed try to check how to extend your root filesystem or free up some space.

Comment: +1.  The OP doesn't need to install packages in other locations, he needs to free up some space in the root filesystem.